# Conversion from explicit to parametric function

Tags: functions

I was given this question:

> Given an explicit function $y = \cos(x)$, propose how to convert it to
> the respective parametric functions $x = f_1(t)$, $y = f_2(t)$?

But I not sure how to solve it. Any ideas or links I could refer to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial parametrization $\,f_1(t)=t\,$, $\,f_2(t) = \cos(t)\,$ will work, unless there are more constraints.

More generally, $\,f_2(t)=\cos\big(f_1(t)\big)\,$ will work for any bijection $\,f_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Do you mind to explain a little bit more?

Comment: @guest176969 For the first one $\,x=f_1(t)=t\,$, so $\,y = f_2(t) = \cos(t) = \cos(x)\,$. Similarly for the second one.

Comment: I see I see thanks so much!